# Data from 2 tables to be sent to excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a table T_Data with 25 columns but I only want these: @Num1, @ClientID, @ISIN, @AllotedQty. I have another table INSTR with multiple columns but I am only interested in 1 column from that, @RefNo

I need to write a stored procedure to export this data to an Excel file including a Header Row
Header of excel file:

```
Num1 | ClientID | ISIN | AllotedQty | RefNo
```

Till now, I have written a code to extract headers but I am unclear in taking union of both where I have to get some columns of T_data and 1 column of INSTR.

```
DECLARE @raw_sql varchar(max)

DECLARE @columnHeader VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @columnHeader = COALESCE(@columnHeader+',' ,'')+ ''''+column_name +'''' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'T_Data'

-- This will give all column names in T_Data. How to omit some columns?

DECLARE @columnHeader1 VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @columnHeader1 = COALESCE(@columnHeader+',' ,'')+ ''''+column_name +'''' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'INSTR'

DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList+',' ,'')+ 'CAST('+column_name +' AS VARCHAR)' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'instr'
```

Also, after extracting data and headers, how to send it to excel?

Comment: Have a look at SSIS. Your job will be done easily using that.